# how to install plugins manager on Jmeter 5.1.1

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm currently working on Apache JMeter 5.1.1
tying to download and install plugins manager but it doesn't seem to be working, does it has something to do with JMeter version ??

I need to install the parallel controller because I have some long-polling requests that take a lot of run time as it waits for the response, so is there any other way around it rather than the parallel controller?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have an open access of the network and there should be no firewall setup on your network than download the JAR file(latest is jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar) from https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/ and add it to the JMeter_Home/lib/ext folder and restart the JMeter.

You should see the Plugin Manager under the Options and from there you can install your desired plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Its same as before. Download the JAR file(latest is jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar) from https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/ and add it to the JMeter_Home/lib/ext folder and restart the JMeter.
You should see the Plugin Manager under the Options